# A curious conjecture: $\{\varphi(m^2)/\varphi(n^2):\ m,n=1,2,3,\ldots\}=\{r>0:\ r\in\mathbb Q\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $\varphi$ denote Euler's totient function. It is easy to see that all those numbers
$$\varphi(n^2)=n\varphi(n)\ \ (n=1,2,3,\ldots)$$ 
are pairwise distinct.

I have the following surprising conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Any positive rational number $r$ has the form $\varphi(m^2)/\varphi(n^2)$ with $m$ and $n$ positive integers.

I have verified this for $r\in\{a/b:\ a,b=1,\ldots,50\}$. My computation shows that 
\begin{align}&\left\{\frac{\varphi(m^2)}{\varphi(n^2)}:\ m,n=1,\ldots,15000\right\}\\\supseteq&\left\{\frac ab:\ 1\le a,b\le 50\ \&\ \{a,b\}\not=\{19,47\},\{37,47\}\right\}.\end{align}
In addition, I have found that
$$\frac{\varphi(12765^2)}{\varphi(18612^2)}=\frac{80879040}{102738240}
=\frac{37}{47}$$
and
$$\frac{\varphi(39330^2)}{\varphi(55836^2)}=\frac{373792320}{924644160}
=\frac{19}{47}.$$

I have no good explanation for the conjecture, but I'm confident that it should be true.

**QUESTION:** Is the above conjecture true? Are there any supporting heuristic arguments?

Your further check of the conjecture is also welcome!

Comment: Did you check if http://oeis.org/A002618 contains relevant information?

Comment: I have checked the sequence and its citations in OEIS, My conjecture is new.

Answer (score 17):

Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$ and write $\alpha=p_1^{s_1}\dots p_k^{s_k}$, where $p_i$'s are prime and $s_i\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. We want to show that there exist $n$, $m$ such that all their prime factors are at most $p_k$ and $\varphi(m^2)/\varphi(n^2)=\alpha$. For that use induction on $p_k$. If $s_k$ is even then we can choose $m=p^{a}m_0, n=p^bn_0$ where $a,b$ are positive integers satisfying $a-b=s_k/2$ and $(m_0, n_0)$ solves $\varphi(m_0^2)/\varphi(n_0^2)=\alpha/p_k^{s_k}$ which exists by induction hypothesis. If $s_k$ is odd and positive we take $m=m_0p^{(s_k+1)/2}, n=n_0$, where $(m_0, n_0)$ solves $\varphi(m_0^2)/\varphi(n_0^2)=(\alpha/p_k^{s_k})/(p_k-1)$. Similarly for $s_k$ odd and negative.

Comment: Great!  It is a nice proof. Thank you!